Can the absense of something be a cause?
I wonder, can the absence of something be a cause? My first inclination is to say yes. For example, if someone is in a room with no air, the lack of air will cause them to die. But what really is the truth of this matter? Also, what have philosophers written about this question?

Yes, any physical condition can be a cause. You gave a correct example. Condition A causes condition B if, supposing hypothetically we had the power of gods and intervened in the universe to set up condition A at an initial time, and then "ran" the universe according to its laws until a later time, condition B would (guaranteed or likely) arise at that later time, provided also that condition B would not be guaranteed or likely to arise had we instead set up a lack of condition A initially.

There is no "truth of this matter", it depends on one's meaning of "cause". And the word is used in multiple senses. Even if we restrict to efficient causes, the answer is controversial and depends on what one takes causes to be, events or facts. If they are facts then absences, non-occurrences and omissions can be causes, but not if they are events, see SEP. There is a similar controversy on whether holes are objects.

I would not say the absence of air that causes death, but that the process of converting energy is halted. A body requires inputs to sustain energy transition, and the process is halted without those inputs. Absence of air implies that the norm is that air is normally present. You would also not argue that the absence of uranium in your house, is keeping you alive. That's not the norm so that sounds weird.

This is a more intriguing question than I would have imagined. For example, in addition to thinking of the room as having an absence of air, what if we think of it as having the presence of a vacuum? But I guess I also consider a hole an object, because it is defined by the circle that forms it. To me, even if humans cannot see a hole in visible light, it can still  be there. A black hole is a great example. It is definitely an object as far as I know.

"For want of a nail the shoe was lost." -- Benjamin Franklin.

People die due to the absence of a floor to stop them from plunging 15 stories.

@Conifold Independent of how philosophers debate "cause" the mind within the body operates on the perception of the presence or absence of items. The presence of philosophers is the "proximate cause" of philosophical debates concerning the meaning of the word "cause" in some social context. Presence and absence are fundamental to the contents of the human mind and thus fundamental to ideas of cause. Galileo argued that a ball rolling horizontally continues forever at constant speed if resistance is absent but slows down and eventually stops if resistance is present. Perceptions of cause!

Note that absence of something can also technically be also  "an absence of an absence". One can ask if the absence of absence-of-air in this room is a cause that enables me to breath...

Even at a fundamental layer, if future states are caused by past states, and "nothing is here" is a possible past state, then absence can be a cause. If you want a tiny universe to use at an example, Conways game of life will suit just fine - a cell being empty in one frame is completely reasonably part of the casual explanation for why it's neighbouring cells take on a particular value in the immediate future

I suppose what motivates your question is that often when we think of causes and effects we have in mind some kind of mechanism whereby some event or feature of a situation gives rise to another. Things cause things to happen. So it makes sense to ask how something absent from a situation can be considered a cause. Or how something that doesn't exist can be a cause. Such things are sometimes called privative causes and there is a fair amount of philosophical literature on the subject. E.g. there are many papers listed here.
Often in our everyday use of causal language, we are concerned with what people do, or don't do, and what the consequences are. This matters to us because our welfare depends a great deal upon what other people do. We also often consider a person's actions to be moral or immoral, especially if they cause harm to others in foreseeable ways. When we think of how people cause things, it is straightforward to extend the concept to cases of things happening because people failed to do something. In law, this concept is called negligence. You can be held liable for things you failed to do that you should have done and could reasonably be expected to have done.
In cases of a failure to act, we often use causal language. What caused these flowers to die? Maybe because Mary didn't water them. But there are billions of people who didn't water them. Why not say: because the Dalai Lama didn't water them? Well, it's not his responsibility, or it's not his usual practice. What we typically do is identify a mismatch between what normally happens and what failed to happen in this case. What caused this aeroplane to crash? Gravity obviously, but that is not the answer we are looking for. Aeroplanes normally cope fine with gravity. We want to know the mismatch between how a plane normally works and what went wrong in this case.
Similarly in your example. We understand that it is a normal state of affairs for people to breathe air. A situation in which a person has no air is highly abnormal, so we identify that as the cause of their death.
This also accounts for how causes are often disputed. Suppose you ask two economists what is the cause of the high unemployment rate in some country.  Johnny might say it is caused by the failure of the government to engage in contracyclical stimulus spending. Freddie might say it is caused by structural features of the job market that are pricing people out of work. In each case, the economists have a model of what they think should normally happen, and what they identify as the cause is the mismatch between that and reality.

There is a famous headline: "Plane Too Close to Ground, Crash Probe Told" Yes, it was too close, it was actually touching the ground. Not supposed to do that while traveling at 2x highway speed. Well, now we know what went wrong. There is a great show, "Mayday - Air Disasters" (there's one for ships also). Fascinating how much effort they can put in and then find the actual, real, true cause of the problem, even from years in the past, and correct it. No need for Philosophers there.

@ScottRowe That's not a real headline, it's a joke that's circulated online in lists of funny headlines for decades, ever since the Usenet days. It just eventually lost the context and turned into one of those "can you believe this really happened" friend-of-a-friend stories that didn't actually happen.

@Idran like so much of what goes on...

A person dies due to the absence of nourishment. Is that even up for debate?

Capitalist markets mean the government enforces private property and contracts. Economics is the field where the government and markets always exist together, in various forms, and wherein the libertarian or free market economist always blames the government for adverse outcomes! In other words, in a counterfactual world, the government would not exist to interfere with the market mechanisms, and the market would be the best possible solution to all social coordination problems! Political problems are coordination problems that we try to solve by means of government and market institutions.

Certainly. The absence of locking bolts in a fuselage plug door will cause the door to blow out in flight. The absence of an O-ring seal in an oil fill port will cause the engine to which it is attached to spew away all its lubrication, causing the engine to catch fire and the plane to crash. Leaving a lug nut off a car wheel will cause the wheel to flex in a way that loosens the other lugs, causing the wheel to come off.

Sounds like you have a lot of experience in this area. You could become a disaster cause investigator, it's a steady job!

Job security supplied by Boeing.

@scott rowe, in a previous lifetime I did root cause forensic analyses of quality catastrophes in large factories. Got to  travel to Ireland, Puerto Rico, Singapore, San Diego and Boise. Spent a lot of time on the factory floor under fluorescent lighting in the middle of the night, and reading engineering memos  while sitting in bed in cheap hotels.

If you mean signal rather than cause (they aren’t fully disentangled concepts in physics for example), then yes. The classic example used by philosophers and philosophers of physics for signals of this sort are in Sherlock Holmes where the dog not barking tells Holmes the murderer was someone the victim knew. This use and attribution to the Holmes case has been used by Tim Maudlin and James Ladyman, among others I’m sure. It’s a common enough useage.
In philosophy of physics this type of signal is often used to demonstrate signals not necessarily requiring matter/energy moving.

Right. Someone I knew didn't get a text message from me and cancelled all our plans and wouldn't answer the phone. I sent the message, but the other phone didn't display it for 4 days. So, no message is not a 'message'. This is the reason for things like the Three Way Handshake that the Internet is based on.

@ScottRowe Presumably, you wanted to say "so, no message is a 'message'"?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica if you never got a reply, what message would that be. He's dead? He hates me? He's too busy? He's been abducted by aliens? All of the above? When the person I referred to didn't receive the message I did send, they interpreted the nothing as something. This is dumb, wrong and unfair. Are phones utterly reliable and perpetually infallible? No? So don't treat them that way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

@ScottRowe It is not dumb, wrong and unfair to assume the probable and draw conclusions accordingly. We are always acting on the basis of incomplete information.  It is, with all due respect, dumb, wrong and unfair to blame somebody for doing so.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica perhaps someone has already done some research into how to function best with incomplete information? I'll just take the probable conclusion that it has never come up before because I personally haven't seen it. I can draw any conclusions from missing information and be fully justified, because Material Implication.

@ScottRowe "Have personally not seen it" does not always equate with "improbable"; in the particular case of a text message it does, though.

Apart from that case I was thinking that you had made a typo because I take it that in the Sherlock Holmes story, "dog not barking" clearly carried information and hence was a message. Hence, painful as the personal story may be, indeed: The absence of a signal is also a signal, information, a message.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica we could use it to start whole new areas of fundamental research: "News Flash! Universe 95% short in accounting figures!" It's a Bitcoin universe I guess, big bubble then a crash.

Interestingly, absence is, in a way, often at least a necessary condition for something to come into existence. Because where there is some physical thing, there often cannot be another thing. Even emotions, ideas, convictions, in general any mental activity depends on free mental capacity — i.e., the absence of competing mental activity. Sufficient absence of stimulation is known to cause sensory hallucinations which fill the void.
A single condition, if necessary and sufficient, may be a cause, or it may be part of the set of conditions which are necessary and sufficient, that is, part of a cause. The absence of incompressible matter inside a submarine, for example, is necessary for it to implode; together with sufficient outer pressure and insufficient structural stability it is the cause for the implosion.

Yes, if submarines were completely filled with water, they wouldn't implode. Some submersible equipment contains mineral oil or something. "Nature abhors a vacuum." Space seems to do ok though.

The trivial answer should probably be: No.
What isn't there can't be the cause of something.
And the most likely reason why people still have an intuition towards the affirmative is that they reverse cause and effect. @Bumble does a great job explaining that in the latter part of their answer.
If you don't start from a cause and evolve things in the forward time direction (into an effect), but instead start with an effect or more precisely the expectation of an effect, then you can blame the discrepancy between IS and OUGHT on the absence of something.
But that is having it backwards, the "normal state" of that universe without air is that you die, it's the presence of air that disturbs that normal state and is the cause of your survival. It's the prescription of a "norm" that renders effects that deviate from that norm an "event" where the "cause" is seen as an absence of... well ironically an absence OF A CAUSE. There was nothing causing it to go in that direction and so it didn't.
Which again exemplifies that it's not actually the absence of anything that caused it, it's the other way around we make up scenarios and things who's presence would have served as a cause. So it's these present things, not their absence that would cause something.
And again Bumble does a good job exemplifying that:

In each case, the economists have a model of what they think should normally happen, and what they identify as the cause is the mismatch between that and reality.

In other words they aren't describing what's real, they are assuming, prescribing and anticipating what is, could be and why it could be. And they might not even be correct about that.
Now despite being wrong and counterfactual this approach is nonetheless very useful, because there are situations with a finite number of outcomes so that the presence or absence of things let you predict the outcome and there are situations where you are or appear to be "looping". So that you can make predictions for the future by looking at the past (or what you recorded of that and are able to look at in the presence), because if you are in a circle going a half-circle in the forward direction and going a half circle in the backward direction means you end up at the exact same point.

Yes, the default state for matter in the universe appears overwhelmingly to be 'dead'. So, don't take the bizarre aberration you are currently living for granted! It won't last. :-)
